# How do you store user-created symbolic math in a database?

Tags: database, postgresql, math, mathml, mathjax

My site requires users to input a great deal of mathematical and scientific notation.  Naturally, I need a way to store this server-side for future use.  This is my ideal course of action:  a user inputs a chunk of text, potentially with or without mathematical symbols, the input is submitted, it is then turned into a format that is suitable for a database, and finally, on every subsequent viewing of the inputted math, it should get converted to MathML.  The MathML is converted to a readable format by MathJax.

I have never worked with storing math in a database before, and the fact that I want to allow users to be able to insert math inline with text creates a few implications.  Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose I could, but I would prefer not to store markup in the db.  Is that how it is done in production for a number of sites?

Comment: I wouldn't know, I haven't stored symbolic math in a db.

Comment: If the database doesn't have to interpret the math then it is just another hunk of textual data for the database to store, toss it in a `text` column and move on to more interesting problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desire to normalize this kind of thing is understandable.  It is also wrong.

The only thing you should "expand" into more semantic types for the use of a relational database is anything that would appear in a `where` clause.

If it's reasonable for you to want to run a query that looks like (pseudocode:)

```
SELECT * FROM FORMULAE
WHERE "/theta" in free_vars(FORMULAE.FORMULA)
AND "bob" in FORMULAE.USERS;
```

Then you want to use a data type that makes such a query efficient.  If, on the other hand, the database will not be doing any kind of processing on the stored formula, then don't try to convert it to or from anything except the most useful external representation, the markup that properly represents the formula.

Answer (score 0):

store the MathML as text.  if it does not fit in a VARCHAR, then use a CLOB

Comment: I guess my comment still stands, do people really store Markup in the db?  If so, do they somehow parse out the equations, and store them in a separate table?  B/c I would hate to have large chunks of text mixed with MathMl in the db, but if that is the only way to do it, then I suppose.

Comment: You can ask at [meta.math.stackexchange.com/](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/) how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing it as MathML text in the database. That way, at insertion time, you convert it to MathML once, then each time it is accessed, there's no need to convert it (ie: faster).

Comment: Right, but how would users edit that math once it's in the db?  Convert back to ascii?

Comment: Oh! Your original post didn't say anything about editing the formula, you only mentioned "subsequent viewing".